# problems with Create a path from a few strings in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, path

I got a little problem. In the following code i recieve a file and the ending of the file from Networkstream. After that the File is saved under the path i received. Everytime i run the code i get the `path.getinvalidpathchars` exception. here is a short code example:

```
        ns.Read(ending,0,1212);
        string endung = "saved." + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ending);
        string path = Path.Combine(@"c:\users\user\desktop\" , endung);
        Console.WriteLine(path);
        File.WriteAllBytes(path ,file);
```

the byte array file is an array of bytes from the file i received. the full path is `c:\users\user\desktop\saved.` and the rest (txt, jpg, exe) should be changebel (that means if the received string sas "txt" the path should be `c:\users\user\desktop\saved.txt` if it sas "exe" `c:\users\user\desktop\saved.exe` and so on)!

Comment: what does `Console.WriteLine(path);` outputs?

Comment: `path.getinvalidpathchars` so probably invalid characters, so what is the full path (not just `c:\users\user\desktop\ ` )

Comment: I am assuming  `Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ending)` is printing invalid filename chars . Check the result of that method

Comment: @Rahul `c:\users\user\desktop\file.(txt or exe or jpg ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem with a StreamReader!

```
        //byte[] file = File.ReadAllBytes(@"c:\users\user\desktop\file.txt");
        TcpListener listen = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(mes),223);
        listen.Start();
        TcpClient client = listen.AcceptTcpClient();
        NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream();
        StreamReader sre = new StreamReader(ns);
        string ende = sre.ReadLine();
        string path = Path.Combine(@"c:\users\user\desktop\file2." + ende);
        Console.WriteLine(path);
        File.WriteAllBytes(path ,file);
        listen.Stop();
```